# Factoring polynomial with two variables

Tags: factoring

Factoring:

> $$f_{n+1}\geq r^{n-2}+r^{n-3}$$
>   Factoring out a common term of $r^{n-3}$ from line (2), we get:
>   $$f_{n+1}\geq r^{n-3}(r+1)$$

I don't understand how to factor out r^(n-3) to get that result.

Comment: $r^{n-3} r^{1} = r^{n-3+1} = r^{n-2}$.

Comment: *What two* variables?

Comment: Which result? btw, r^(n-3) = (1 + (r-1))^(n-3), use extended binomial theorem here

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla r and n

Comment: $r^{n-2}+r^{n-3}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-2$ in *one* variable.

Comment: @abstractnature I think you are confused. It is just $r^{n-2}+r^{n-3}=r^{n-3}(r+1)$. No binomial theorem needed.

Comment: why is r^(n-3) a common factor of both? is it different than positive exponents where we would expect r^(n-2) to be the common factor?

Answer (score 2):

$r$ to any power is a common factor of both. I'm sure you are familiar with the following rule for exponents: $r^a \cdot r^b = r^{a+b}$. The other thing you need to know is that $r^0 = 1$. Using this, we can factor out $r^c$ from any expression of the form $r^x + r^y$:

$$
r^x + r^y = r^c ( r^{x-c} + r^{y-c})
$$

In this case, we have $x=n-2$, $y=n-3$, and $c=n-3$, which gives $r^{n-3}(r+r^0) = r^{n-3}(r+1)$.